# How can I connect my rails app to the server when using postgresql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a rails app which uses postgresql database.  This is the first time i have used it. postgresql is installed and pgAdmin loads ok, but there is no connection to any server.  The strange thing is that i have connected to the localhost:3000 before with this app, but now i get the following error message when i try to connect:

```
PG::ConnectionBad

could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Extracted source (around line #56):

    ### Convenience alias for PG::Connection.new.
    def self::connect( *args )
        return PG::Connection.new( *args )
    end
```

database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: unicode
  username: postgres 
  password: #not sure what to put here

development:
  <<: *default
  database: nutri_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: nutri_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: nutri_production
  prepared_statements: false
  encoding: unicode
```

So far i have watched youtube videos on seting up postgresql and read the guides, but in my case there are things missing like connections to servers. i have found no answers to this question on here. i am utterly lost on this one so please make any advice step by step. postgresql is completely new to me. if there are any other files i should post in an edit let me know.

Comment: Have you checked if postgres is correctly running? What OS are you using?

Comment: you have postgresql installed and running on your computer correct?

Comment: @RockwellRice. yes, i have pgAdmin4 opened but there are no servers.

Comment: @Sebastian Palma . i have windows 10. the gui opens so i assume its running correctly. although it the first time i have used it so i dont know.

Answer (score 0):

If you install PostgreSQL then click to icon like this

[image]

and if you have not set a password before, then software ask to set a password then the use this on your database.yml file, if not asking for a password then you can create this manually, click to open the server on the left side of pg admin dashboard `server->PostgreSQL->Login/Group->postegres`

[image]

right click on mouse then go to properties click to `Definition` tab then set your password.

That's it done!

Hope to help